# High F-Statistic Value and negative Probability for Granger Causality Result, Interpretation?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, vector-auto-regression

I tested the hypothesis: SwissFranc/USD does not Granger Cause S&P500 and received an F-Statistic of 69.1 and a probability of 2E-51. How do I interpret this result and can the probability be 2E-51, so negative? Having trouble stating the result of the test. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood the notation.  `2E-51` is not a negative number, but machine notation for the number $2 \times 10^{-51}$, which is equal to $$0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002.$$  This corresponds to the probability of observing a value of the $F$-statistic at least as large as $69.1$ by random chance, assuming the null hypothesis is true (in your case, no effect).

Comment: Just to clarify, if it is a very low positive number doesn't this mean that the null hypothesis can be rejected as the probability is below 0.05 and the alternative hypothesis would be accepted that SwissFranc/USD does granger cause S&P 500 with very low probability?

Comment: @CleverseekerRover1 Assuming you applied the hypothesis test correctly, and the model assumptions are valid, the conclusion is to reject the null hypothesis.  I have no idea what the hypothesis means, so it is up to you to draw the appropriate inference.